# How to understand which maven dependies would writen in jar as libs?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I don't understand how does jar builds from our application.

project structure looks like this:

```
parent
--child1
--child2
...
--child10
```

Research child2.jar

```
child2/pom.xml has 20 dependies
```

`child2.jar/OSGI-INF/lib` contains only part of this dependies(jar==dependency)(<20)

I am bad with maven - please help to find place where this list configures?

Comment: It's configured in the pom.xml, but the dependencies can have different scopes also, which may exclude them. Do they have a scope defined?

Comment: child2.snapshot jar will be in your workspace where parent project is and inside parent project a folder of child2>target>child2SNAPSHOT.Jar will be present if your project build successfully.

Comment: @cy3er yes they have diferent scope (exis without scopes too)

Comment: So which scope do the excluded ones have?

Comment: Regardling cy3er's question: you can check that easily by running mvn dependency:tree .

Answer (score 0):

A dependency added in pom.xml will download all jar files required for that entry. For example if a dependency API is based on Spring MVC, by adding the dependency in pom.xml it will download the Spring jars required for that as well.

Its always better to use maven whenever you go for a new project as it helps building and wrapping the war file much easier.

You can refer [Maven in 5 mins](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) for a quick glance of functionalities.

[Findjar](http://www.findjar.com) will help you identify the pom dependencies for almost all class/jar files

Comment: **A dependency added in pom.xml will download all jar files required for that entry** - can I use these dependies in my project ?